# Space between two words in a table LateX

Tags: tables

I am trying to set a table in which I want to include some pictures. I tried different models of table, but I have two problems : 
1. The table is really long and can not fit in one page. I can't find where to modify it (and how =)). 
2. There is no space between words in my table (for example, it is written "AmphoredeKos" instead of "Amphore de Kos"). I don't know how I can modify this.

If someone could help me, that would be really nice !! 
Thank you a lot =) !!

```
Table 1 : Liste des échantillons prélevés au DRASSM 25.02.2019 textbf{-Partie 1-}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{$\displaystyle}Sc<$}
\cellspacetoplimit=2pt
\cellspacebottomlimit=2pt

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|*{7}{C|}} \hline \hline
    Ref.  &  Photo  &  Typologie  &  Informations sur l'\acute{e}chantillon  &  Poix  &  Tesson  & Objet \\ \hline \hline

    6545    &  
        \begin{minipage}{.13\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=20mm, height=20mm]{IMG_0716_min}
        \end{minipage} 
        &   Dressel 5    & Amphore de Kos  &   &   &  X \\ \hline

6828A   & 
\begin{minipage}{.13\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=20mm, height=20mm]{IMG_0718_min}
    \end{minipage}
    &                &   & X & X &  \\ 
    \hline
```

Comment: Why are you setting math mode?

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I am not sure I understood correctly your question ? What do you mean by "Math mode" ?

Comment: @LouCh: You could try with ` \begin{tabular}{|l|*{7}{c|}}` and `l'échantillon`. If you want to have italic text, use something like `\textit{your text}`.  For includeing graphics in y table you might also be interested in the `valign=t` option offerd by the `adjustbox` package.

Comment: You put `\displaystyle`between $ and $, which triggers mathmode.

Comment: You can split some of the titles over multiple lines, or perhaps use an acronym and a footnote with the full title.,

Answer (score 1):

The following MWE contains three different versions of your table.

In the first version, I have used the `valign=t` option in order to align the images with the text in adjacent cells. Additionally, I have used the `cellspace` package for some vertical white space and adjusted the horizontal white space around the images to match ter vertical white space. I have also used the `makecell` package in order to split up the column header of the 4th column into two lines so that the table is narrower and can fit into the textwidth. In oder to get a caption, I have used the `table` enivronment in combination with the `\caption` command.

In the second table, I have used the `tabularx` package in order to make the table as wide as the textwidth. This might be useful if the 4th column contains longer text.

In the third example, I have removed the vertical lines and replaced the horizontal lines by rules from the `booktabs` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % Remove the demo option in your real document.
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage{makecell} % Only for the first table

\usepackage{tabularx} % Only fr the second and third table

\usepackage{booktabs} % Only for the third table
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Liste des échantillons prélevés au DRASSM 25.02.2019 \textbf{-Partie 1-}}
\cellspacetoplimit=2pt
\cellspacebottomlimit=2pt
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|@{\hspace{2pt}}Sc@{\hspace{2pt}}|*{6}{c|}} \hline \hline
    Ref.  &  Photo  &  Typologie  & \makecell[cc]{ Informations \\ sur l'échantillon}  &  Poix  &  Tesson  & Objet \\ \hline \hline

    6545    &  
        \includegraphics[width=20mm, height=20mm,valign=t]{IMG_0716_min}
        &   Dressel 5    & Amphore de Kos  &   &   &  X \\ \hline

6828A   & 
      \includegraphics[width=20mm, height=20mm,valign=t]{IMG_0718_min}
    &                &   & X & X &  \\ 
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\caption{Liste des échantillons prélevés au DRASSM 25.02.2019 \textbf{-Partie 1-}}
\cellspacetoplimit=2pt
\cellspacebottomlimit=2pt
\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|@{\hspace{2pt}}Sc@{\hspace{2pt}}|c|X|*{3}{c|}} \hline \hline
    Ref.  &  Photo  &  Typologie  & Informations sur l'échantillon  &  Poix  &  Tesson  & Objet \\ \hline \hline

    6545    &  
        \includegraphics[width=20mm, height=20mm,valign=t]{IMG_0716_min}
        &   Dressel 5    & Amphore de Kos  &   &   &  X \\ \hline

6828A   & 
      \includegraphics[width=20mm, height=20mm,valign=t]{IMG_0718_min}
    &                &   & X & X &  \\ 
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{Liste des échantillons prélevés au DRASSM 25.02.2019 \textbf{-Partie 1-}}
\cellspacetoplimit=2pt
\cellspacebottomlimit=2pt
\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l@{\hspace{2pt}}Sc@{\hspace{2pt}}cX*{3}{c}} 
    \toprule
    Ref.  &  Photo  &  Typologie  & Informations sur l'échantillon  &  Poix  &  Tesson  & Objet \\ \midrule

    6545    &  
        \includegraphics[width=20mm, height=20mm,valign=t]{IMG_0716_min}
        &   Dressel 5    & Amphore de Kos  &   &   &  X \\ 

6828A   & 
      \includegraphics[width=20mm, height=20mm,valign=t]{IMG_0718_min}
    &                &   & X & X &  \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey !

Thank you for this very well explained anwer ! 
I did understand a little bit more now.

However, I have a list of 25 samples to include in the table and it does not fit in the same page. So I would like the table to be continued over few pages depending on the size of the table. For now, I am compiling three different documents that list all the samples and I would like to have only one document that could contain all the samples over 2/3 pages. 

Do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: @LouCh: In order to get a table that automatically spans multiple pages, you will need a `longtable`. If you want to use this in combination with the variable width `X` type columns from the `tabularx` package, you will need one of the following packages: `ltxtable`, `ltablex` or `xtabular`.