# How to insert pictures in first column of a table (tabular)

Tags: tables, diagrams

I am using tabular for a table and would like to insert in the first column little pictures instead of text. Is there an easy way to do this? See picture below for example.
Thanks
Andy
[image]

Comment: You should give a M(inimal) (Not) W(orking) E(xample).

Comment: You can insert images with `\includegraphics` wherever you want.

Comment: See answer on question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/603595/how-to-fill-table-cells-with-an-image. You only need to change the columns order (and make table (far) less fancy :-)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/479663/134144 could also be helpful.